# Yii-user AfterLogin callback

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using the Yii-user module in my project, and I wonder if there is some "afterLogin" callback I can use to run some code of my own (By now I just need to add a couple of variables to the session) if the user is correctly authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public function actionLogin(){
    //all your stuff for login action
    //after validated login
    if(Yii::app()->user->id){
         $this->addVariablesToSession($param);
    }
 }
```

Add this function in the same controller
This store as many variables in session after successful login.

```
 public function addVariablesToSession($param){
      Yii:app()->session["variable_name"] = $param;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but if you look at [WebUser.php component](https://github.com/mishamx/yii-user/blob/master/components/WebUser.php)

You may notice that there's a afterLogin() function.

Comment: yes, I noticed the `protected function afterLogin($fromCookie)`, but not sure of using directly. I wonder if there is a more enduser-solution. Thanks

Comment: Well, if you're altering component's session, i guess it makes more sense to alter it on a lower level) Anyways, good luck and thanks for the rep.